# having html problem with fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

im currently working on adding content to an external ajax file being loaded with fancy box and fancybox is cutting off my content.
http://imstillreallybored.com/pdf/pdf/

can somebody please help me resolve this?

Comment: alright which id or class has 365px? ive been updating code as we speak maybe it was something i was testing and alright ill try that

Comment: image set height and width seemed to work, but im afraid if text goes farther then the images it will cutoff. What do you think?

Comment: i dont think so.  The fancybox was actually the size of the DIV containing the text.  I assume if text goes farther then the images, the fancybox will size according to that perticular size. In fact, the text doesn't have to load and because of that, fancybox recognises its height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason why your fancy box has 365px in height? If not, problem might be in fancybox creating the "dialog box" before the image where actually loaded. If every image are the same size, you should write  so that even tho the image is not loader yet, the JavaScript getting the total DIV height will still get the correct size.

Answer (score 3):

At `#fancybox-overlay` change attribute `position: absolute` to `position: fixed`..

Answer (score 1):

See the [options for FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/api), specifically the `scrolling` option.

If that (*somehow*) doesn't work, then using CSS: on `#fancybox-content`, add `overflow-y: auto`.

Comment: i dont want it to scroll though i want everything viewable its supposed to resize to the div content height and width im thinking its possibly a clearfix issue

Comment: I see, try this: on your outermost `div` (`<div style="width:680px;">`) in `less-cost.html`, add `overflow: hidden` to clear the floats.

Comment: which div am i adding overflow:hidden to?

Comment: To the `div` on the first line in this file: http://imstillreallybored.com/pdf/pdf/less-cost.html - that will clear your floats as you asked - but, I don't think this will fix your actual problem.